# How can i get odoo environment in thread

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, environment

I'm trying to make a function to send a message to a specific user for this in my model I wrote this code

```
class SkypeBot(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.skype'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity', 'res.users']
    _description = 'My Skype'


    skype_login = fields.Char('Your skype Login')
    skype_password = fields.Char('Your skype password')
    skype_message = fields.Char(store=True)

    @api.multi
    def msg(self, message):

        partner_id = self.env['res.users'].search([('id', '=', 2)]).partner_id.id

        _logger.info('^^^^^' * 5)
        _logger.warning(partner_id)
        _logger.info('^^^^^' * 5)

        self.env['mail.message'].create({'message_type': 'notification',
                                         'subtype': self.env.ref('mail.mt_comment').id,  # subject type
                                         'body': message,
                                         'subject': 'Message subject',
                                         'partner_ids': [(4, partner_id), ],
                                         # partner to whom you send notification
                                         })
```

I need to connect the odoo environment to thread which I call here so that I can calmly call the msg method from the SkypeBot class and send a message to the user. How to do it right

```
class MySkype(skpy.SkypeEventLoop):
    def onEvent(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, skpy.SkypeNewMessageEvent):  

            message = ('New message from user {} at {}: \'{} \''.format(event.msg.userId,
                                                                   event.msg.time.strftime('%H:%M dd. %d.%m.%Y'),
                                                                   event.msg.content))


            _logger.info('--------'*5)
            _logger.warning(event)
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)
            _logger.warning(message)
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)

            sbot = skype_model.SkypeBot()
            sbot.msg(message)

from skpy import Skype

sk = MySkype('+375', '1239qW', autoAck=True)
thread = threading.Thread(target=sk.loop)
thread.start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this code

```
import odoo
DB_NAME = 'YOURDBNAME'
ODOO_CONF = '/opt/odoo/configurations/odoo.conf YOUR CONF PATH'
UID = odoo.SUPERUSER_ID
odoo.tools.config.parse_config(['--config=%s' % ODOO_CONF])
with odoo.api.Environment.manage():
     registry = odoo.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(DB_NAME)
     with registry.cursor() as cr:
          # Load our context and environment given the database cursor and UID
          ctx = odoo.api.Environment(cr, UID, {})['res.users'].context_get()
          env = odoo.api.Environment(cr, UID, ctx)
          # INSERT YOUR ENV 
          message = env['my.skype'].msg()
          try:
              cr.commit()
          except Exception:
              cr.rollback()
              raise
```

but you must install odoo properly (odoo in dist-package) or this import odoo will not detected by python (error module named odoo not found), if import odoo is not detected by python just place your code in your odoo folder to make this work

Comment: Do I need to change something in the UID, or does odoo find the id itself

Comment: лют 14 12:25:59 PK odoo12[9538]:     registry = odoo.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(DB_NAME)
лют 14 12:25:59 PK odoo12[9538]: AttributeError: module 'odoo.modules.registry' has no attribute 'RegistryManager'

Comment: Did you install odoo from source (python setup.py install)? if not try to place your script in odoo folder

Comment: Try python in terminal, follow this instruction https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#porting-from-the-old-api-to-the-new-api
if error, thats mean youre not installing odoo properly

Comment: yes i install odoo from setup. but i use odoo as a service (daemon) maybe the problem is related to this